# How canon is Star Wars: Battlefront (2015)?

Tags: star-wars, video-games, canon, star-wars-battlefront

The 2015 video game *Star Wars: Battlefront* is largely a multiplayer shooter.  But it was released after the [*Star Wars* canon wipe of 2014](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/910/1027), so it's ostensibly canon.  Obviously the accomplishments of each player isn't canon, but the settings and scenarios should provide some new bits of canon.

Which elements of *Star Wars: Battlefront (2015)* are canon?

Comment: Tempted to downvote. The game has no story whatsoever. I don't think Emperor Palpatine ran around on a battlefield in Endor.

Comment: @tilley31 One of the scenarios is a speeder bike chase on Endor, you want to argue that isn't in canon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the "Legends" brand was introduced, the [announcement](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page) mentioned that "all *Star Wars* creative development" would be coordinated, and Lucasfilm President Kathleen Kennedy specifically mentioned games:

> We’re set to bring *Star Wars* back to the big screen, and continue the adventure through **games**, books, comics, and new formats that are just emerging.

Regarding *Battlefront* (2015) specifically, an employee of the developer (DICE) stated that its canon status is ["complicated"](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/04/29/star-wars-battlefront-canon-is-complicated). Outcomes which contradict canon (e.g. the Empire winning at the Battle of Endor) would obviously be non-canon, but everything else in the game is made to be as canon as possible.

For example, DICE often traveled to the real-world locations where the Original Trilogy was shot (such as California, for [Endor](http://starwars.ea.com/en_GB/starwars/battlefront/news/the-star-wars-battlefront-planets-creating-endor-uk)), and [DICE designed the planet Sullust with Lucasfilm's approval](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/04/29/star-wars-battlefront-canon-is-complicated):

> Sullust, as seen in Battlefront, is the Lucasfilm-approved version of the planet. Nothing appears in Star Wars anymore without substantial deliberation, and with no proper "Expanded Universe" in Lucasfilm's current lexicon, the Sullust created by DICE is Sullust.

[Photogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry) was used on the [original props](http://starwars.ea.com/en_GB/starwars/battlefront/news/how-we-used-photogrammetry-uk) (such as the Death Star and Darth Vader's helmet) so characters, vehicles, ships, etc. are as realistically dimensioned as possible. [DICE was given access to the original sounds from the films](http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/news/creating-the-sounds-of-star-wars-battlefront), so the sounds are also as true to the films as possible.

It's also worth noting that [the canon summary listed in *Star Wars: A New Dawn* includes *Battlefront*](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/03/27/new-star-wars-infographic-reveals-updated-canon):

[image]

(Technically, this is referring to the novel [*Battlefront: Twilight Company*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battlefront:_Twilight_Company) which was based on the game.)

Perhaps the best way to describe the game's canon status is: **everything in the game which doesn't contradict existing canon is itself canon.**