# Is Boba Fett alive in the new canon?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, boba-fett

In the EU/Legends material Boba Fett fought his way out of the Sarlacc's guts- Has there been any announcements or anything to suggest he survived getting swallowed by it in the new films (from TFA and beyond)?

Comment: As C-3PO says in Return of the Jedi, people eaten by the Sarlacc experience new forms of suffering as they are "slowly digested over the course of a thousand years".  The Sarlacc keeps them alive during that period.  This answer explains how:  http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43415/does-the-sarlacc-pit-keep-its-victims-alive

Comment: "In its belly, you will find a new definition of pain and suffering as you are slowly digested over a thousand years."   Dead people don't feel pain and suffering.

Comment: @WadCheber That's assuming Fett didn't shoot himself after the first thirty years of unimaginable pain and suffering

Comment: @Jason Baker - Let's not forget his utter incompetence that landed him in there in the first place. Even if he could escape, do we have any confidence he would be able to after his performance on the barge? Looks like Obi-Wan isn't the only one whose failure is complete.

Answer (score 21):

In the (Disney Canon) series *The Mandalorian*, Boba Fett is indeed alive, however we do not know fully how he escaped the Sarlacc.

He makes his first appearance is S02E01, *Chapter 9: The Marshal*, at the end of the episode in a quick cameo.

[image: Boba Fett face reveal]

Retroactively, we also saw his feet, cape, and arm in the closing moments of S01E05 *Chapter 5: The Gunslinger*.

[image: Boba Fett first appearance]

He is then fully introduced in S02E06, *Chapter 14: The Tragedy*, fighting along side Din Djarin.

[image: Boba Fett alongside Din Djarin]

Boba is being played by Temura Morrsion who is the same actor that played Jango Fett in the prequel trilogies. Since Boba is an unaltered clone of Jango this makes good sense.

Answer (score 12):

A set of Madalorian armor which is implied to have been Fett's is seen in Star Wars: Aftermath

> From the box, he withdraws a helmet. Pitted and pocked, as if with some kind of acid. But still-- he raps his knuckles on it . The Mandalorians knew how to make armor, didn't they? "Look at this," he says, holding it up. "**Mandalorian battle armor**. Whole box. Complete set, by the looks of it. **Been through hell and back.** I think my boss will appreciate this."

However, this doesn't necessarily mean that Boba Fett is alive, just that his armor somehow made it out of the Sarlacc. (He could have died afterwards.)

Comment: @JasonBaker It looks to me like it was supposed to be a reference to Fett, without actually confirming that he is alive. But yeah, it could have just been a red herring. (Also, full disclaimer, I never read the book.)

Comment: Yeah, I missed the acid reference on my first look; now I definitely see the Fett implication

Comment: Just because the armor went "through hell and back" doesn't necessarily mean its Fett's armor, or even that it hints that the armor has been scarred by digestive acids. It could just as easily be anyone's else armor that has seen its share of battles.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point Mandolorians get into some of the most dangerous situations as anyone in the universe.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Boba Fett Fan Club](http://www.bobafettfanclub.com/news/fettpedia/schrodingers-fett-the-life-death-paradox-of-boba-fett/), the LucasFilm Story Group brought up Fett at Celebration Anaheim in 2015; according to them, he's [Schrödinger's Fett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat):

> > "Boba Fett is both simultaneously alive and dead in the Sarlacc."
>
> *[...]*
>
> What [Pablo [Hidalgo]](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pablo_Hidalgo) meant by the quote, as explained by further context of his point during the panel, is that Lucasfilm's Story Group has not independently decided one way or the other that Boba Fett is alive nor dead after the fall in the Sarlacc Pit.

However, Fett appears as a playable "Hero" character<sup>1</sup> in the recently-released *Star Wars: Battlefront* video game:

[image]

*However* however, since the canonical status of *Battlefront* is ["complicated"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112429/how-canon-is-star-wars-battlefront), that may not necessarily be a confirmation of his survival<sup>2</sup>:

- Vader and Palpatine are also playable heroes in *Battlefront*, despite them not appearing in some of the playable maps, and being dead for others (like the Battle of Jakku DLC map)
- Similarly, Fett is playable in some maps where he, canonically, does not appear; Hoth, for instance:

  [image]

I haven't played the game, so I can't comment on the situations where Fett appears.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Battlefront* games are typically multiplayer shooters, where you play as ground troops: Stormtroopers, CLone troopers, CIS droids, Rebel soldiers, what-have-you. If you collect enough widgets, you can temporarily play as a main character from the films, with different powers and higher stats, who is associated with your faction. The most recent *Battlefront* game (the one I'm talking about) has [six playable Heroes](http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/features/heroes-villains)

<sup>2</sup> Hat-tip to Tom.Bowen89 for bringing up these points

Comment: I don't see being a character in Battlefront as any kind of evidence of his survival, as Vader and the Emperor are all also characters in Battlefront.

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89 That's a fair point, and I've added a note. Then again, the Battles of Hoth and Endor both appear in the game, which would be sensible places to put either Vader or Palpatine. Do you know which maps Fett is playable on?

Comment: I have only played the beta, and have friends with the game. I believed all characters could be on all maps. Luke also wears his black "Return of the Jedi" clothes in every map, so I'm fairly sure it's completely non-cannon and anything "cool" is fair game.

Comment: Further to that, here's Boba Fett on Hoth:
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xjnyxHf1Tb8/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: [How canon is Star Wars: Battlefront?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112429/5184)

Answer (score 0):

In Star Wars: Aftermath -life debt- there is an interlude on Tatooine where they talk about how the Sarlacc became partially exposed after jabbas barge crashed around it. And that Jawas have been cutting into and looting the creature. It is possible that he could have been freed this way and that is likely how the Mandalorean armor was also attained. Whether he was alive when found or not though doesnt get explained. Though at the same time they reference finding skeletons. But at the same same time there is no way he could have been a skeleton if his armor was stil intact and as referenced it takes a thousand years for the sarlacc to digest.

Comment: Can you provide a quote from the novel?

Comment: no need as this is basically a duplicate of the answer from Ibid