# How does Boba Fett die

Tags: star-wars, boba-fett

How does Bobba Fett die?
If you know the movie can you include it please?

Comment: Related: [Is Boba Fett alive?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114977/31394)

Comment: WATCH THE MOVIES

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### In the most embarrassing way ever:

He's standing on a skiff when a blind Han Solo accidentally whacks his jet pack with a stick.  The jet pack ignites, launching Boba Fett into the side of Jabba's sail barge.  Then he bounces off and rolls into the Sarlacc Pit, where he "finds a new definition of pain and suffering as he is slowly digested over a thousand years."

Reference:  *Star Wars - Episode VI:  Return of the Jedi*

This demise has been parodied more than once by *Robot Chicken Star Wars*:

Comment: Technically, by lack of oxygen to the brain.

Comment: @CreationEdge - Technically, by being digested.  http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43415/does-the-sarlacc-pit-keep-its-victims-alive

Comment: Cause of death is always lack of oxygen to the brain. Either it gets destroyed and can't get any, or other organs fail/get destroyed, leading to an inability to supply oxygen (and maybe some other stuff) to the brain.

Comment: Anyway, I once read the novel featuring a story where Boba actually escapes the Sarlaac  (naked, his armor having been digested). Not canon any longer, but worth mentioning.

Comment: @CreationEdge kinda the opposite of the new canon, [where we only know that the armor survived](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114980/55866).

Comment: @ibid: That quoted reference is vague enough that it could easily be referring to anyone's armor that has seen its share of battle, not necessarily Fett's specifically.

Comment: Who says he died

Answer (score 1):

As of about five years after the events of Return of the Jedi, Boba Fett is not yet dead.

The new series *The Book of Boba Fett* will continue Boba Fett’a story from *The Mandalorian, Season 2* where Boba Fett remains very much alive.