# So is Slave I (Boba Fett's ship) just sitting there, abandoned, near Jabba's Palace?

Tags: star-wars, boba-fett

After blowing up Jabba's sail barge, Luke and R2 leave in his X-Wing, while the rest of the gang leave in the Falcon. But Boba Fett may or may not be getting out of the Sarlacc, and his ship is probably in the palace hangar if it has one, or else is parked nearby, probably visibly. For the amount of effort the rebels spend for every little ship, you'd think they'd take it. Or, if Solo and Fett still have a canon rivalry, maybe they'd blow it up.

It seems Lucas completely forgot about Fett's cool ship, and so did everyone else.

Comment: I think the answer is we don't know. The Aftermath books show that Fett's armor has turned up on Tatooine and is in use by someone else, but there is not yet any indication as to Fett's whereabouts. How the armor came to be out of the Sarlaac isn't addressed either fwiw

Comment: Presumably not. In the *Aftermath* books, scavengers have Fett's armor - it's very unlikely that the ship is just sitting around.

Comment: According to the Novelization, Boba Fett survived the encounter with Sarlacc. If that is the case, he could possibly take care of his ship.

Comment: Although I personally do not like this cliffhanger. Dead is dead. In this case the answer is: 'Unknown, possibly taken apart by scavengers, or stolen by someone'.

Comment: which novelization @TimSparrow? there are a couple now that hold canon status - for example: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!

Comment: according to this story, which comes from a source via word of god (lucas) - Fett lived: http://makingstarwars.net/2014/07/boba-fett-lives-fett-die-star-wars-episode-vi-according-george-lucas/ - since Lucas is a bit out of the loop now though - what does Hidalgo say? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114977/is-boba-fett-alive-in-the-new-canon

Comment: @NKCampbell here is more on that: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114977/is-boba-fett-alive-in-the-new-canon

The stuff I read was old, don't remember author name, but it was an official Star Wars book.

Comment: lol @TimSparrow - we linked to the same question :D - great minds

Comment: I guess we won't find out until the new canon-lords decide Fett's fate.

Comment: This is a good question. Trying to consider it from the characters' perspective, the ship might be a nice thank-you gift to Lando, especially considering his previous dealings with Han.

Answer (score 9):

In current canon, Boba Fett has recovered *Slave I* and uses it again around 9 ABY. This is shown in *The Mandalorian*'s Season Two.

In *The Book of Boba Fett*'s Episode 4: The Gathering Storm,

> its recovery is shown in detail. Bib Fortuna had apparently been keeping it in the garage of what had formerly been Jabba's palace:
>
>  [image: Screenshot from The Book of Boba Fett showing Slave I in Jabba's garage, with Boba Fett and Fennec Shand looking at it]
>
>  Boba recruits Fennec Shand to sneak into the palace with him and recover his ship. While dozens of guards try to stop their attempt, they are ultimately successful and manage to escape with the ship from the garage.

Answer (score 4):

*Slave I* was not forgotten about, as you assert. It merely lost its history in 2014 when Disney de-canonized the EU.

In Legends, it was abandoned in orbit around Tatooine for many years before coming back into the possession of Boba Fett. The ship was later mostly destroyed in a fight with the *Millennium Falcon* but was repaired again at some future date. *Slave I* was operation again by the time the Yuuzhan Vong invasion. There was no record of (final) destruction in the EU, and was still in use by Fett in 41 ABY.

But yes, in current canon, as far as we know, *Slave I* is just sitting there, abandoned, near Jabba's Palace.