# Does Darth Vader ever run?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

My son wants to know if Darth Vader isn't able to run or if he just doesn't want to. My recollection is that he never runs, only struts. Even in the new Rebels shows, I can't think of any instances of him running. Perhaps this was written into Lucas' character description *"DV never runs!"*

Are there any images of him running with full Darth gear on? *i.e. not as Anakin*.

If he doesn't run, then is this due to immense self-confidence that he doesn't need to, or is it a limitation of his suit or a medical impediment, such as his breathing apparatus not able to keep up with fast-paced breathing?

Comment: It looks dignified, but I bet the reason is that suit is petty uncomfortable, thats why all the force choking instead of sprinting over & chopping off body parts. Even grievous got a better deal.

Comment: Check this out: https://i.imgur.com/2KxkLam.jpg 
:-D

Comment: @CanadianGirlScout Once he is in the suit his body is pretty heavily battered. He likely can't, even if he wanted to. BUT that said, he doesn't really need to. Everywhere he goes, they will wait for him. The only time he may need to run is combat, but we never see him in a situation where it is necessary so we don't know for sure!

Comment: He probably leaves the running to everyone around him.  Except for the guy he's after.

Comment: He doesn't require fast-paced breathing.. He can force rush to beat even fastest runners. I have used force rush in video games.

Comment: I think @Odin1806 got the reason. In addition there is no-one around that would be a challenge to him. Luke may have gotten close - but refused to fight him.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Yes

In the canon novel [*Lords of the Sith*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lords_of_the_Sith), Vader was forced to run when he was chased by lyleks on Ryloth (along with the Emperor and two [Royal Guards](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Emperor%27s_Royal_Guard)):

> Vader took position beside his Master as the four of them continued down the tunnel. He sought a place where they could stop and hold their ground, but the tunnel went on and on, not narrowing, with its downward slope diving ever deeper into the planet.
>
> **Drawing on the Force as he ran**, he gestured at the ceiling and took hold of several large chunks of crystal stalactites. He rocked them loose with his power, then let them dangle there, waiting for the vibration of the passing horde to cause them to fall.
>
> <sub>**p. 209**</sub>

Vader can also be seen running in the video game [*Star Wars Battlefront* (2015)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Battlefront), which [is canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112442/31936). For example, here is a video from the single player mission "The Dark Side" in which Vader is seen running at various times:

Answer (score 4):

According to [Can Darth Vader RUN - Star Wars Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfBO3SarJHs), at 2:04 - 2:13 it says:

> Because of the large amount of mass the overall armor contained, Vader did not often run, **but was still capable of doing so, if necessary**.

And it shows footage from *[Star Wars Battlefront II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Battlefront_II_(2017_video_game))* (2017)—which *is* part of canon—where Vader is shown running in sprint mode (in *[Battlefront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Battlefront_(2015_video_game))* (2015), in Legends, he merely "glided" in sprint mode instead of run).

Comment: Only the single player storyline is canon

Comment: The video you've linked to appears to be some sort of fanmade nonsense.

Comment: I've edited the answer to clarify that we're talking about the 2015 and 2017 *Battlefront* games, not the 2003 and 2005 ones. That said, 2015 *Battlefront* can't be considered Legends, since that designation is only for stuff that's pre-Disney. Instead, it would be non-canon (in other words, there is no such thing as new Legends stuff during the Disney era).